# Fixing Compiz windows bleeding effect after snapping windows

Tags: unity, ati, compiz, 14.10, hp

I have a slight problem with windows bleeding and not showing up right on Ubuntu 14.10.

When I snap a window to be fullscreen, i.e. Google Chrome, there is a bleeding effect that happens and moves the windows slightly so I can't see the window buttons and see a bit of the scroll bar.

Is there anyway to fix this issue?

HP Envy dv6-7213NR
5 GB Ram
500 GB, dual-booted Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.10
AMD Radeon HD 7420G